# EER Subtyping differences in symbol placement

Tags: entity-relationship, modeling

I have a simple question regarding the use of sub-type symbol in the EER model. I gave example diagrams bellow. My question is what is the difference between using the subtype symbol `"U"` in the line from parent to subtype or from subtype to parent, for more clearity, see example diagrams bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any reference using the second notation.  Unless otherwise defined, we could choose to read it as equivalent to the first, though it challenges the reader to determine *why* a different notation is used.  For the sake of effective communication, I would recommend honoring the existing convention.